# Linking errors in visual c++ <error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sqlcxt>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I've created a project in Visual Studio 2005, on a Windows 7 64 bit, using Oracle 11g libraries. I'm facing the following problem on linking stage:

> > error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sqlcxt

Which library defines the _sqlcxt?
I have linked my project to the orasql11.lib and checked that it's searching for this librabry (setting Show progress VERBOSE).
Are there any other libraries missing?

I need to solve this problem urgently.

Comment: Is the project configuration set to 64 bits?

Comment: Are you building 32-bit or 64-bit binaries? Is your Oracle client install 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Luchian, how to set the project configuration to 64 bits?

Comment: @Zada in visual studio - build toolbar - you have your build configurations: `debug/release` and `win32/64` or similar.

Comment: Luchian, how to set the project configuration to 64 bits? I've active solution platform Win32. Is it related to this? I've tried to create a new platform but the option list defines 3 choices (Pocket PC 2003 (ARMV4), Win32, Smartphone 2003 (ARMV4))

Joachim, yes my Oracle db install is 64 bit (i'm not using Oracle client 11g, i'm using instead the libraries of Oracle database 11g coz i don't have Oracle client 11g installed)

thank you one more time

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable hints. The problem was solved. It seems that i had to install the compiler 64 bit (that's why i didn't have the option x64 among the list of possible configurations) and then set the VC++ project settings of the x64 configuration and then compile.